# Can I add multiple columns to Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS SQL 2012

I want to do something like

```
select a, b, c, a+b+c d
```

However a, b, c are complex computed columns, lets take a simple example

```
select case when x > 4 then 4 else x end a,
     ( select count(*) somethingElse) b,
     a + b c
order by c
```

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably do this:

```
SELECT
    sub.a,
    sub.b,
    (sub.a + sub.b) as c,
FROM
(
    select 
        case when x > 4 then 4 else x end a,
        (select count(*) somethingElse) b
    FROM MyTable 
) sub
ORDER BY c
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a nested query or a common table expression (CTE) for that. The CTE syntax is slightly cleaner - here it is:

```
WITH CTE (a, b)
AS
(
    select
        case when x > 4 then 4 else x end a,
        count(*) somethingElse b
    from my_table
)
SELECT
    a, b, (a+b) as c
FROM CTE
ORDER BY c
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do this:

```
select a,b,c,a+b+c d
from (select <whatever your calcs are for a,b,c>) x
order by c
```

That just creates a derived table consisting of your calculations for a, b, and c, and allows you to easily reference and sum them up!